# Unable to display image in browser.Which is added dynamically in canvas tag.But able to see in inspect element

Tags: javascript, html

I am able to dynamically pick image path from .JSON file but the image is not able to display. Please refer link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4F5V.png
And when I inspect in the console I am able to see the image in canvas tag but it is not getting displayed in a browser.Please refer this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/48wdy.png
I have also attached code for the same with comments from where I am creating image tag with source dynamically and then appending it to a canvas tag.

```js
 function loadFile() {
    var input, file, fr;
   var c2 = document.getElementById("our-canvas");
     var c2_context = c2.getContext("2d");

    input = document.getElementById('fileinput');
      file = input.files[0];
      fr = new FileReader();
      fr.onload = receivedText;
      fr.readAsText(file);


    function receivedText(annotations) {
 var table_grid = ''; 
      let lines = annotations.target.result;
      var obj = $.parseJSON(annotations.target.result);
   var imgpath = obj[0].ImageFilePath;
   var par = document.getElementById('imageDiv');
   //Generating img tag dynamically 
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  // setting img path from json file 
  img.src = imgpath;
  // adding dynamically created img of a drawing to canvas
  c2.appendChild(img);
  
$.each(obj, function(key,value) {
table_grid += '<tr>';
    table_grid += '<td align="center">'+value.CenterPointX+'</td>';
    table_grid += '<td align="center">'+value.OriginYConverter+'</td>';
    table_grid += '<td align="center">'+value.Width+'</td>';
    table_grid += '<td align="center">'+value.Height+'</td>';
    table_grid += '</tr>';
    
    $('#data_grid').append(table_grid);
// plotting rectngls on img file for each dimension 
    c2_context.strokeRect(value.CenterPointX ,value.OriginYConverter  , value.Width, value.Height);

});
    }
  }
```

```html
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<head>
<title>Dyanamic_SW_Utility</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body style="background-color:#FBEEE6;">
<div style="background-color:#e5e5e5;padding:15px;text-align:center;">
  <h1>Visual Validation Utility - Version 1.0</h1>
</div>
<br />

<div class="container">
<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="window.location.reload()"><br><br></section>
<div class="table-responsive">
<b><p5 style="color:red;">Upload JSON File</p></b>
<form id="jsonFile" name="jsonFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

  <fieldset>
    
     <input type='file' id='fileinput' accept=".JSON">
     <input type='button' id='btnLoad' value='Plot Annotations' onclick='loadFile();'>  <br /> <br />
  <pre id="json"></pre>
  </div>
 <canvas id= "our-canvas" class="image-container" width="1000" height="1000"> </canvas>
 <div id=" "></div>
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="data_grid" align="center"> <br /> <br />
      <tr align= "center">
       <th align= 'center'>Center Point <i>X</i></th>
       <th align= 'center'>Origin <i>Y</i> Converter</th>
       <th align= 'center'>Width</th>
       <th align= 'center'>Height</th>
      </tr>
 </table>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<script src="app.js" > </script><br>

</div>
<!-- <input type="file" id="filepicker" name="fileList" webkitdirectory multiple /> -->

<!-- <ul id="ImagePreview"></ul> -->
 <!-- <div id="imageDivPNG"></div> -->
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try prefixing your image urls with `file:///` since you're loading it by the filesystem, rather than through `localhost` or something like that.

Comment: But what if, I want to pick the file from the file system. Actually, this is the requirement.

Comment: After you select the file, if it doesn't have `file:///` in the path, add it before sending it to the canvas. Normally if you were running a server, you'd upload the file to a location and then reference that location.

Comment: I added it before sending it to the canvas. its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To View Image in Canvas This is the Perfect

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('our-canvas'),   //canvas element is part of HTML and allows for dynamic, scriptable rendering of shapes mages.
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    uploadedFile = document.getElementById('uploaded-file');
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',initImageLoader) ;

function initImageLoader(){  // this load the image on web page 
    // uploadedFile.addEventListener('change',handleManualUploadedFiles); // this select the selected file to view on web page 
    function handleManualUploadedFiles(ev){
        var file = ev.target.files[0];
        handleFile(file);

    }   
}
function handleFile(file){             // this function is to upload image format file likes PNG and JPEG Files 
    var ImageType = /image.*/;

    if(file.type.match(ImageType)){

        var reader = new FileReader();        // this read selected image file 

        reader.onloadend = function(event){
            var tempImageStore = new Image();         // stores the image on web page 
            tempImageStore.onload = function(ev){
                canvas.height = ev.target.height;
                canvas.width = ev.target.width; 
    context.strokeStyle="#FF0000";
                context.drawImage(ev.target,0,0);
            }   
            tempImageStore.src = event.target.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);                
    }   
}
```

```html
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<head>
<title>Dyanamic_SW_Utility</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body style="background-color:#FBEEE6;">
<div style="background-color:#e5e5e5;padding:15px;text-align:center;">
  <h1>Visual Validation Utility - Version 1.0</h1>
</div>
<br />

<div class="container">
<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="window.location.reload()"><br><br></section>
<div class="table-responsive">
<b><p5 style="color:red;">Upload JSON File</p></b>
<form id="jsonFile" name="jsonFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

  <fieldset>
    
     <input type='file' id='fileinput' accept=".JSON">
     <input type='button' id='btnLoad' value='Plot Annotations' onclick='loadFile();'>  <br /> <br />
  <pre id="json"></pre>

  </div>

 <canvas id= "our-canvas" class="image-container" width="1920" height="1024"> 
 </canvas>
 
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="data_grid" align="center"> <br /> <br />
      <tr align= "center">
       <th align= 'center'>Center Point <i>X</i></th>
       <th align= 'center'>Origin <i>Y</i> Converter</th>
       <th align= 'center'>Width</th>
       <th align= 'center'>Height</th>
      </tr>
 </table>
  </fieldset>
</form> 
<script src="app.js" > </script><br>

</div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">

  function loadFile() {
    var input, file, fr;
   var c2 = document.getElementById("our-canvas");
     var c2_context = c2.getContext("2d");

    input = document.getElementById('fileinput');
      file = input.files[0];
      fr = new FileReader();
      fr.onload = receivedText;
      fr.readAsText(file);
    function receivedText(annotations) {
 var table_grid = ''; 
      let lines = annotations.target.result;
      var obj = $.parseJSON(annotations.target.result);
   var imgpath = obj.ImageFilePath;
   var par = document.getElementById('imageDiv');
  //Generating img tag dynamically 
var img = document.createElement('img'); 
// setting img path from json file
img.src = imgpath;
<!-- c2.appendChild(img); -->
img.onload = function() {
    c2.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0,0);
 $.each(obj.labledData, function(key,value) {
table_grid += '<tr>';
    table_grid += '<td align="center">'+value.CenterPointX+'</td>';
    table_grid += '<td align="center">'+value.OriginYConverter+'</td>';
    table_grid += '<td align="center">'+value.Width+'</td>';
    table_grid += '<td align="center">'+value.Height+'</td>';
    table_grid += '</tr>';
    
    $('#data_grid').append(table_grid);
    // plotting rectngls on img file for each dimension 
    context.strokeStyle="#FF0000";
    c2_context.strokeRect(value.CenterPointX ,value.OriginYConverter  , value.Width, value.Height);

    
});
}

    }
  }
</script>
```

[PLEASE REFER SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nRmP.png) **Perfect Solution**